# Make the aggregation function in the form menu more versatile for different projects?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, aggregation, data-source

I have expressions for a table field that has a map layer named as a data source file (building_ex.shp). I plan to save this setting as a style and use it in other projects, but in other projects the layer with this data source file can be named differently (BUILDINGS; real estate; facilities).

Is it possible to make this expression more universal, so as not to change it in each project?

[image]

Comment: Did you consider "project variables"? You can access them by using @project_variable - perhaps there is a hidden solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. Admittedly, the expression can probably be cleaned up.

```
with_variable('existing_layer_name',
    with_variable('options', array('buildings', 'facilities', 'real estate'),  -- pre-determined list of layer names 
        with_variable('layer_names', array_foreach(@layers, layer_property(@element, 'name')),

            array_get(@options,
                array_filter(
                    array_foreach(
                        @layer_names,
                        array_find(@options, @element)
                    ),                      
                    @element > 0
                )[0]
            )
        )
    ),

    -- the original expression
    aggregate(
        layer:=@existing_layer_name,    -- the result of the matching procedure above
        aggregate:='sum',
        expression:="value"
    )
)
```

It basically matches the layer names in the project against a pre-determined list. If more than one match is found then it uses the first one.

`array_find` returns the index of the found element, and `array_get` uses that index to pull the layer name from the array of 'options'. `array_filter` is used to remove any `-1` returned by `array_find` (non-matching).

The following two screenshots omit the original expression to demonstrate what is returned by the match.

[image]

[image]